# When Is A Constructor/Properties Really Necessary in .Net?

Tags: vb.net, constructor

Very quick question as I have never really understood the need for a constructor/properties in some cases... I have a class called "Validation" where all I plan to do is take in a value from some textboxes and be sure that they are either filled in or proper format. I can get functions to work and return values without a constructor or setting private fields and properties for them.

So, why even bother? Is there a good reason? Example code below:

**Function Call:**

```
Dim validation As New Validation
Dim allFields As Boolean = False
allFields = validation.testFunction("Yes")

    If allFields = True Then
        MsgBox("Success")
    Else
        MsgBox("Fail")
    End If
```

**Class:**

```
Public Class Validation

    Function testFunction(randomField As String) As Boolean

        If randomField = "Yes" Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If

    End Function

End Class
```

So, why should I bother with a constructor and declaring _randomField with a property if it does what I want it to with that little code? Thanks.

Comment: Classes with properties/fields are used when you need to store related data in a single object. In your case you don't need to store any data, so the answer is: You don't bother (and infact shouldn't) add properties nor a constructor. You don't even need to create an instance of the class. You can remove `Dim validation As New Validation`, mark the function as [`Shared`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/shared) and call it like this instead: `allFields = Validation.testFunction("Yes")` (notice the uppercase `V`).

Comment: Nobody is forcing you to have a constructor in you class. It's a design choice based on the class functionality. It can be quite useful to initialize a class with some values that alter/define the way it works. You could also have static (Shared) methods. Backing fields are also optional. You can use Auto properties. You are the designer. Your choices.

Comment: It's probably more appropriate for `Validation` to be a `Module` than a `Class` (in the code given here) since the purpose is to contain a stateless function.

Comment: "Really needed" is hopelessly subjective.  VB.NET doesn't require it, you can put all of your code in Modules.  But if you start to learn object-oriented programming then you'll inevitably discover that you can't do without them.

Comment: `Dim validation As New Validation` with this line of code you are calling the default constructor of your class. This constructor is created for you automatically.

Comment: For the given example the testFunction method could've been Shared which would alleviate the need for the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

When you want something to always execute when a new instance is created, you use constructor. But it also depends on the different pattern (ex, factory pattern might initialize outside of the constructor).

When you start having more logic in your program like Dirty state or Attributes they are done with properties because of the added possible logic. Same with having private setter and public getter. But some of this could be done with method instead.